# I can't filter fields in model (Django)

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models, filtering

I have models (removed all unnecessary):

```
class Contract(models.Model):
    contract_number = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    student = models.ForeignKey('Student', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    lessons = models.ManyToManyField('Lesson')
class Student(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    age = models.IntegerField()

class Lesson(models.Model):
    lesson_time = models.TimeField(verbose_name='Время урока')
    lesson_date = models.DateField(verbose_name="Дата урока")
    is_done = models.BooleanField(verbose_name="Проведен")
```

In my HTML I use special link:

```
<a href="{%url 'stud_detail' id=student.id%}">
```

which leads to URL in `urls.py`:

```
path('student/<int:id>', views.one_student, name='stud_detail')
```

And there is my view (again removed all other models):

```
def one_student(request, id):
    student = Student.objects.get(id=id)
    contracts = Contract.objects.filter(student=id)
    lessons = Lesson.objects.filter(id__in=contract)
    print(lessons)

    content = dict(student=student,
                   contracts=contracts,
                   lessons=lessons)

    return render(request, 'studbase/student_detail.html', content)
```

Now I have 10 lessons in the contract, but based on filtration results I have only one.
print(lessons) returns only 1 lesson instead of 10 lessons.

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You are filtering `Lesson`s such that the primary key somehow corresponds with the `id` of the `Contract`s, but that does not make much sense.

You can filter with:

```
lessons = Lesson.objects.filter(contract__in=contracts)
```

Comment: Thank you, it's worked)) A little correction is lesson__in=contracts, but it finally works)

Comment: @RomTurino: that is likely because you have set the `related_name='lesson'`?